# Win 10 home, endless bootloop, no troubleshoot screen or bios access

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios

I have a Lenovo Notebook which has entered a endless bootloop after an update.

After i press the power button, there is a blank screen, then the "Lenovo" logo shows up with the loading circle beneath. This goes on for about 5 seconds. Then the screen goes blank again, and a small blank window briefly appears, before the update screen shows for 0.1 seconds and it reboots. Problem is that i cannot even attempt to fix this, as i get no access to BIOS or the troubleshooting screen. I'm looking for a solution to get access to this.

What i have tried:

1. Powering on and off a few times until automatic repair starts. This does not work and no matter how many times i try to manually switch the computer on and off, the automatic repair / troubleshoot screen never appears.
2. Holding F8 / F12 / F4 / F10 / Windows-key and so on while powering the notebook on. Nothing happens.
3. Letting the battery drain out, and then removing it. Then holding the power button for 30 seconds. After reassembly and powering the pc on again, the boot up is still the same.
4. Creating a bootable USB media, and connecting it and booting up the pc. This does not work either or i am possibly doing it wrong. Again, i cannot enter the bios and choose which media to boot from.

All google solutions i could find assume that you can access the bios or troubleshooting page, and are therefore not helpful.

Edit:
Suggestions from this post that i've tried but have not worked:

1a. Unplugging the battery and manually powering off the laptop by plugging / unplugging the adapter multiple times, in hope of troubleshoot screen / auto repair. This did not work.

Comment: "Powering on and off a few times until automatic repair starts. This does not work " It has to be a hard shutdown, remove the battery, then unplug the power cord when that window briefly appears, do this 3 times.

Comment: I have now done as you suggested, and still no luck. I took the battery out and plugged / unplugged at your suggested time, multiple times and the boot up is till doing the same thing

Comment: Then the problem is before windows starts to load. More than likely a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions: Some Lenovo products have a small Novo button on the side (next to the power button) that you can press (you might have to press and hold) to enter the BIOS setup utility.  Check and see. Otherwise it is the F1 or F2 key.

Another choice might be to create a bootable CD or DVD(assuming it has a drive)and try to boot from that.

Another thought; Is the hard drive removeable? It is probably going to the hard drive first, then getting hung. Try removing the hard disk. You should get the "No disk found" error, but that's ok, it may give you the option to enter the BIOS from there. Good luck keep us posted on how you're doing.

Comment: Novo key did not work unfortunately. Tried your third suggestion and i'm happy to report that i was given access to the UEFI / BIOS. I set the USB with windows installation media as boot drive, and i am now trying to restore the PC. Will keep you posted.

Comment: System restore did not work. For some reason there is no option to reset the PC. My options are Uninstall windows updates (Does not work), System Image Recovery (Can't find any available image), Startup Repair (No help) and Command Prompt. Tried Bootrec /RebuildBcd on all available drives but it doesn't detect any Windows installations. So i'm guessing the main drive has got its windows installation wiped ?

Comment: Alright, i finally managed to fix it. Problem was that i was trying to restore the wrong drive (lol). Rookie mistake i guess. Thanks for helping me get to the BIOS / UEFI.